# Cleaner method of SelectedRowIndexes for a jqxgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

For a single row select grid is there a cleaner method to getting the selected row instead of doing a for loop on the indexes as illustrated in the following example?

```
var ParentAccount = $("#jqxSubAccountDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('selectedrowindexes');
for (var index in indexes) {
    _row = $(_Object).jqxGrid('getrowdata', index);
    var ParentAccountGuid = _row["AccountIndex"].toString();
    break;
}
```

Basically, I need to pull the Guid or index out of the selected row of the grid and then send that along with other data to an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

According to a JQ Widgets example, the following should work:

```
ParentAccountRowIndexes = $("#jqxSubAccountDropdownGrid").jqxGrid('selectedrowindexes');
if (ParentAccountRowIndexes.length > 0)
{
    ParentAccountRowData = $(_Object).jqxGrid('getrowdata', ParentAccountRowIndexes[0]);
    ParentAccountGuid = ParentAccountRowData["AccountIndex"].toString();
}
```

As soon as I can confirm it I will post my results.